# How to transform mass density in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

(I assume spherical symmetry.)

In comoving coordinates $(T,R,\Omega)$, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}^{(1)}$ the (proper) mass density is $\rho^{(1)}$.

In other coordinates $(t,r,\Omega)$, with metric $g_{\mu\nu}^{(2)}$, what is $\rho^{(2)}$?

The Jacobian transforming from $(T,R,\Omega)$ to $(t,r,\Omega)$ is $J$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\rho^{(1)} = \mathcal{T}_{TT}^{(1)}$$

and

$$\rho^{(2)} = \mathcal{T}_{tt}^{(2)}$$

where $\mathcal{T}_{\mu\nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor.